# Connecting door strike to relay

Tags: arduino, relay

First of all I know there are many similar questions answered but I'm still a bit unsure on why my current set up doesn't work. I'm really outside my area of expertise so be kind.

This is what I have:

1. A door strike from Assa. See datasheet:
   [image: Assa door strike datasheet]
2. 6 wire cable connected to door strike. I don't want to to dismantle the door to see how it's really connected so I'm assuming red / black is positive and blue / white is negative. Does that seem correct?
3. Arduino that controls a relay. This part works.
4. DC Power adapter - 12V 1A

So I have connected the positive wire from the power adapter to the com port on the relay. Then I have twisted together the red and black wires from the strike and connected it to the NC port on the relay.

Then I have connected the negative wire to the blue and white wires.

But when the relay switches on nothing happens. What have I done wrong? What should I do to trouble shoot it. Should I add a diode like in datasheet?

Comment: You should add a schematic of your complete circuit. *Should I add a diode like in datasheet?* Uhm, it is in the datasheet so why would you **not** have it present?

Comment: Assume nothing. Test the connectivity of the 6 wires with the door open, and again when locked. Then update your question with the information if you are still puzzled. As the data sheet shows a diode connected across the red and black wires, twisting them together sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: One side of the strike coil should be connected to the relay NO terminal, not the NC.  The COM terminal is connected to NC when the relay is released, and to the NO terminal when the relay is operated.

Comment: why would you involve a relay in initial troubleshooting? .... briefly connect the 12VDC directly to the strike solenoid ..... does it unlock?